# How to get the last charactor you put in an ostream object out

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm doing a programming work, it's like this

```
vector<Member> members;
stringstream ss;
stringstream ss1;
for (vector<Member>::iterator it = members.begin; it != members.end(); it++){
     ss << it->name << ",";
     if (check(it->id)){
         ss1 << it->name << ",";
     }
}
```

so, at last ,there will be a "," that I don't need, I want to get that out of ss, how to do this, I know I can use some varible to control this in for, but I think Directly manipulating ss will be more convenient
the method provide by some friend here can not handle the situation of ss1,  how can I control the "," of ss1.
and Can someone tell me why ostream can not give back any data but istream can putback data

Comment: Just use a conditional statement. I doubt that you can take it out of stream (and even if you can, it is just round-about: you put in something then you take it out).

Comment: Consider printing the ", " before you print the name for all but the first which would be when `it == members.begin()`

Comment: thank you, it's a good way,I think I may use it,   but I still want to know is it possible to manipulate ss to get the last charactor out, I check the io library doc, but didn't find it

Answer (score 1):

An ostream, by name, is an *output stream*: it is not designed to give you back any data.

Even if it did, however, your code will be much cleaner using a simple condition:

```
vector<Member> members;
stringstream ss;
for (vector<Member>::iterator it = members.begin(); it != members.end(); it++) {
    if (it != members.begin()) ss << ", ";
    ss << it->name;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much , I adopt your method.  you said an output stream is not designed to give back any data, I guess it's right, I don't find any method in iostream any way

Comment: @user1462782: The idea of a strem is a *channel* that transport a value after make it in textual form towards another place.   It is conceptually like a send-mail: once you place it in the box, it's gone and does anymore belongs to you.    If your stream, intead of be directed to a string, was directed to an output port connection, how can you get back the data you transmitted?

Comment: thanks, but why istream has a method  putback to putback the last charactor you extracted from the stream

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking if you are writing the last element you can write the first one and delimiter before each next element:

```
vector<Member> members;
stringstream ss;

vector<Member>::iterator it = members.begin;
if(it != members.end()){
    ss << it->name;
    for (it++; it != members.end(); it++){
         ss << ", " << it->name;
    }
}
```